# How can i make my child item clickable?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, parent-child

Actually i'm trying to develop an restaurant that will permise to take orders.

But actually i'm having some issues while adding a variant to my food.          I'll explain better, i have a recyclerView "FOOD" from which i add items to another recyclerView "NOTEBOOK" something like a waiter got note of what someone ordered.

Also in my app i'm able to add to the FOOD added to the NOTEBOOK some variants in other words i've added PIZZA to my NOTEBOOK and with variants i can add a child to PIZZA called "BIG" or "WITH PEPERONI" or both.

for adding a child i've doing the following in my Adapter

```
public class AdapterPTERM extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPTERM.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private List<ItemPTERM> mExampleList;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface  OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_pterm,parent,false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v,mListener);
    }

    AdapterPTERM(Context context, List<ItemPTERM> exampleList){
        mExampleList = exampleList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ItemPTERM item = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getBtnName());
        holder.qta.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuant()));

        holder.variantsContainer.removeAllViews();


        // ADDING CHILD HERE

        final List<Variant> variants = item.getVariants();
        if (variants != null && variants.size() > 0){
            for(Variant v : variants){
                View vView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.variant_layout,holder.variantsContainer,false);
                TextView nameTV = vView.findViewById(R.id.variant_name);
                nameTV.setText(v.getName());
                vView.setTag(position);
                vView.setOnClickListener(varientClickListener);
                holder.variantsContainer.addView(vView);

            }





        }


        // NOT IMPORTANT (CHANGING FIELDS COLOR
        if(position % 2 == 0 ){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));

        }else if(position % 2 == 1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView qta;
        private LinearLayout variantsContainer;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            qta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);
            variantsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_child_items);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }


    private View.OnClickListener varientClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("VIEW:", "CLICKED");

        }
    };

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mExampleList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

}
```

Now i would be able to click every single child item i've added or even add one onSwipe method because i would be able to delete specific variants from a food.

Here is a screenshot of how my recyclerView look's like with the recyclerView and child.

[image]

Now how can i use the onClick in my activity?

Comment: Just set the `OnClickListener` on each added View . You can set Tag for data to added `View`.

Comment: @ADM can you make an example and what do you mean with Tag? i've just started to work with android

Comment: Because actually the View's can be a lot so i have to create OnClickLisntener for every of it? I actually don't even know how many variants there can be

Comment: It will be much easier to achieve what you are trying to do using expandable recyclerView. This is the line that you add in your gradle dependency compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:x.x.x and this is an example project of how it works: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: @JohnKarry you need to learn how the adapter works actually :). There is only one clickListener and that will work with all of your items because you will be giving position to it like ADM said. And the way you are doing you will face problem better use expandable recyclerview or listview.

Comment: Ok thank you guys, ill try to use the Expandable recyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a global `OnClickListener` and set listener to all variant views.

```
 public class AdapterPTERM extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPTERM.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private List<ItemPTERM> mExampleList;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    View.OnClickListener varientClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Click","Called");
        }
    };
    ........
}
```

Set listener to each added view And set position as tag and get it back when view is clicked.

```
 List<Variant> variants = item.getVariants();
    if (variants != null && variants.size() > 0){
        for(Variant v : variants){
            View vView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.variant_layout,holder.variantsContainer,false);
            TextView nameTV = vView.findViewById(R.id.variant_name);
            nameTV.setText(v.getName());
            vView.setTag(position);
            vView.setOnClickListener(varientClickListener);
            holder.variantsContainer.addView(vView);
        }
    }
```

Now you cam modify the listener as :

```
View.OnClickListener varientClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getTag()!=null){
                int position= (int) v.getTag();
                // Use position to process data 
            }

        }
    };
```

You can set multiple tags . See `setTag` method's variants.

Comment: How can i create a global OnClickListener?

Comment: I've actually made a public interface called varientClick and just placed in it the 1st method of your answer is it right?

Comment: Yeah . `setTag()` i have used because we usually need to position of view which is clicked . You can get it by tag and also some other data you want . Apart from that you can try using Expandable `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

Comment: While the 3rd method from your answer have to be placed in the activity?

Comment: I just updated my question with what i'm trying to do with your code can you check what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why `MyClick.varientClickListener` ? Just use it as i have mentioned . Create it Globally inside adapter . And put a Log inside it you will see if it will get called on click or not . See the updated answer .

Comment: Ok i've got it i hadn't had to create an interface, but now how can i use that onClick in my activity? when i'm trying to put the 3rd method from your activity it says varientClickListener is never used

Comment: Getting messy!!! if you get onclick event in Adapter you can just provide a callback to Activity. Thats why i have mentioned `setTag` in first place cause you have to know which item position is clicked .  Or you can Define varientClickListener in `Activity` itself and pass it to adapter with constructor .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174041/discussion-between-johnkarry-and-adm).